# Zip the contents of a folder without including the folder itself

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a directory called `folder` that looks like this:

```
folder
      -> root_folder
                    -> some files
```

I want to zip this directory into `zipped_dir`, I tried:

```
zip -r zipped_dir.zip folder/*
```

But this generates a ZIP that looks like this:

```
zipped_dir
          -> folder
                   -> root_folder
                                 -> some files
```

in other words, it's including the directory whose contents I want to zip. How can I exclude this parent directory from the ZIP, without moving anything?

IE I would like this end result:

```
zipped_dir
          -> root_folder
                        -> some files
```

Answer (score 198):

Try to use this command (you will get the idea)

```
cd folder; zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip *
```

Maybe there is other way, but this is fastest and simplest for me :)

Comment: this works perfectly doing that trick. note: it will do a `chroot `.

Comment: equivalent: `zip -r zipped_dir.zip folder/*`

Comment: @TobiasKolb, maybe you do not read the question. OP do not want to have **folder** in to the stored path in zip.

Comment: Seems the only way to do

Comment: this won't add hidden files

Comment: I would use `pushd` instead of `cd` so you can come back to the same location with a `popd`.

Comment: @PabloDiaz, in my example `cd -` will do the work (only one command) :) Or `cd ..`

Comment: @RomeoNinov true, as long as you don't mind losing history of the previous folder. You can push/pop infinite number of folders.

Comment: If you want to include hidden files `zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip .* *`

Comment: It actually works. In my case was to level down 
`cd folder/folder; zip -r ../../zipfile.zip *; cd ../../`

Comment: small addition: use (cd folder; zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip *) - the ()'s run the commands in a subshell so it doesn't change your directory

Comment: @chrisdowney, right, it can be used :)

Comment: For anyone looking to achieve the same for updating an existing zip file: `cd folder; zip -ur ../zipped_dir.zip .`

Answer (score 100):

Use `-j`; for example: `zip -r -j zipped_dir.zip folder/*`

It won’t zip 'root_folder'.

Comment: I get an error with this one if I have two files of the same name.

Comment: OP probably wants only the parent directory removed, not all of them.

Comment: Still creates directories `zip -r -j package.zip ./dist/static/*` makes archive structure `dist/static/myfiels`

Comment: it flatten's child directory files as well.

Comment: the `-j` option eliminate all directory info and only save files. That is, to store all files under one directory in a "flat" way.

Answer (score 17):

```
zip -r -D zipped.zip *
```

`-D` instructs zip to not create directories.

Comment: doesn't seem to be a valid option in mac os zip

Comment: Works in macos. Don't forget that using `*` will exclude hidden files, so I ended up using `.`:
`zip -D -r ../archive.zip .`

Comment: This doesn't work for the simple reason that files aren't directories. Zip stores files with full filenames like `folder/root_folder/some files/filename.txt` (note that the filename contains slashes). -D just prevents directory-file entries like `folder/root_folder/some files` to be included., but the files **in** that directory are still included.

Answer (score 15):

This is what works for me:

```bash
7z a zipped.zip ./rootDir/*
```

It will create a `zip` archive with root: any files/directories inside `rootDir`. e.g

```
zipped.zip:
     file1.txt
     otherdir/
        file2.txt
```

#### Hidden files:

As correctly pointed on [`@Shiva Wu`'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-without-including-the-folder-itself/544448?noredirect=1#comment1091030_544448) the above **does not include hidden files**.

This is **also the case for the rest of the answers** (at least the ones which  preserve directory structure). One **solution** is to explicitly **add the hidden paths wildcard**.

```bash
# The command below will include (among other) all files and directories starting with a dot.
7z a zipped.zip ./rootDir/* ./rootDir/.[!.]*
```

**OR**

```bash
# Same as above in one argument
7z a zipped.zip ./rootDir/{*,.[!.]*}
```

result:

```
zipped.zip:
     file1.txt
     .hiddenfile1.txt
     .hiddendir/
        file3.txt
     otherdir/
        file2.txt
```

Comment: You can actually use your original solution and include hidden files, just add `shopt -s dotglob` before the `7z` command

Answer (score 2):

Note that you may get an error (`bash: /usr/bin/zip: Argument list too long`) when using Romeo Ninov's answer if you are zipping many thousands of files. To avoid this, use a `.` instead of a `*`, like so:

```bsh
cd folder
zip -r ../zipped_folder.zip .
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `-r` option, the "zip filename" and the list of items I want to add into it. Refering to `--help` option we get:

```
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
```

You can go into folder that contains the files and directories you want to zip in. The run the command:

```
zip -r filename.zip ./*
```

The result is a `filename.zip` containing everything into the directory you ran the command.

Adding a command for hidden files, we can use `ls -a` from shell put after `zip` command (already in the directory that contains your desired files):

```
FILES=$(ls -a)
zip -r filename.zip $FILES
```

For fish users, just change `FILES=$(ls -a)` to `set FILES (ls -a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Improved answer with all comment suggestions:

```bash
# Include parenthesis so cd does not affect your current terminal
(cd folder; zip -r ../folder.zip ./)
```

Hidden files will be included too!