# Zip the contents of a directory without the directory itself

Tags: command-line, zip

I want to create a ZIP archive of a directory without going into the directory itself, and not include that directory

[Zip the contents of a folder without including the folder itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032) - This post guides to changed the current directory and then create the archive. But, as stated earlier, i do not want to change the current directory.

This is the structure of the directory that I want to archive

```
parentdir/
parentdir/dir1/
parentdir/dir1/file1.txt
parentdir/dir1/file2.txt
parentdir/dir2/
parentdir/dir2/file1.txt
parentdir/dir2/file2.txt
```

And the desired archive would contain

```
dir1/
dir1/file1.txt
dir1/file2.txt
dir2/
dir2/file1.txt
dir2/file2.txt
```

If I use the command

```
zip -r output.zip parentdir/
```

this includes the `parentdir` as well in the archive.

Is there any flag that allows us to create an archive without the `parentdir` ? I do not want to change the current directory to the `parentdir`. I cannot also use the `-j` flag,since I do not want to junk the rest of the paths. Can i accomplish this from any directory?

Comment: (1) Your constraint sounds arbitrary — like “I need to get dressed, but I don’t want to open the closet door (where my clothes are) or reach into the closet.”  If you explained the *basis* (reason) for your stipulation, (a) you might get more sympathy (and, consequently, more effort and more/better answers), and (b) it might turn out to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271976), and we might be able to solve your *real* issue.  (2) If not going into the directory itself is an essential part of the problem statement, you should probably mention it in the question title.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of such a flag to `zip`. You say:

> I do want to change the current directory to the `parentdir`

by which I *assume* you mean you do *not* want to change to the `parentdir`. Under that assumption, I would use:

```
(cd parentdir; zip -r ../output.zip .)
```

Comment: Sorry about that.. The intended phrase was "I do not want to change the current directory to the parentdir" .