# Zip a file without including the parent directory

Tags: zip

I have a folder that contains multiple files

> folder
>
> - artifact1.app
> - artifact2.ext2
> - artifact3.ext3
> - ...

My goal is to zip the file from outside this folder (so without using `cd` command) without including the folder dir.

```
zip -r ./folder/artifact.zip ./folder/artifact1.app
```

This command includes the folder dir in the final zip. Any hints?

Related question: [Zip the contents of a folder without including the folder itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-without-including-the-folder-itself)

Comment: From the man pages, it seems like only `-j` would apply, and that'd compress all folders into a single root-level directory within the ZIP. That's not what you're looking for, is it?

Comment: @phyrfox Maybe yes. Need to verify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to store all the files in `folder` under their name without a directory indication, you can use the `-j` option.

```
zip -j folder/artifact.zip folder/artifact1.app folder/artifact2.ext2 folder/artifact3.ext3
```

or

```
zip -j folder/{artifact.zip,artifact1.app,artifact2.ext2,artifact3.ext3}
```

If you have files in subdirectories, they won't have any directory component in the archive either, e.g. `folder/subdir/foo` will be stored in the archive as `foo`.

But it would probably be easier to change to the directory. It's almost exactly the same amount of typing as the brace method aboe. If you do that, if you include files in subdirectories, they'll have their relative path from the directory you changed into, e.g. `folder/subdir/foo` will be stored as `subdir/foo`.

```
(cd folder && zip artifact.zip artifact1.app artifact2.ext2 artifact3.ext3)
```

For interactive use, you lose shell completion this way, because the shell doesn't realize that you'll be in a different directory when you run the `zip` command. To remedy that, issue the `cd` command separately. To easily go back to the previous directory, you can use `pushd` and `popd`.

```
pushd folder
zip artifact.zip artifact1.app artifact2.ext2 artifact3.ext3
popd
```

If you want full control over the paths stored in a zip file, you can create a forest of symbolic links. Unless instructed otherwise, `zip` doesn't store symbolic links.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly list all the files in the the subdirectory (`folder`), you can just use a wildcard, i.e. `zip -j folder/*`

Comment: Relying on shell expansion means that dotfiles (e.g. `.profile`) won't be included in the archive. Instead, change the current working directory and specify `.` as the file to be archived: `cd folder && zip -r ../folder.zip .`